# Select and copy a particular cell in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have 4 columns in my `tkinter treeview`.  The last column consists of `url links` in the form of `text`.

I would like to `enable` the users to click on the `url cell` they desire and they be able to `copy` it.  Is this possible?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that `tree` variable has a *Treeview object*. First, you should bind an event handler to `tree`. Then, in your event handler function you can use `tree.focus()` to find out which tree item is focused now. Next, you need to identify which column the current cell has - `tree.identify_column` method can help with it. Finally, you can check whether it is the needed column. If it is so, you append the cell value to clipboard.

Here's a code example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def tree_click_handler(event):
    cur_item = tree.item(tree.focus())
    col = tree.identify_column(event.x)
    if col == '#3':
        root.clipboard_clear()
        root.clipboard_append(cur_item['values'][2])

root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.pack()

tree['columns'] = ('one', 'two', 'three')
tree.column('#0', width=170, stretch=tk.NO)
tree.column('one', width=100, stretch=tk.NO)
tree.column('two', width=100, stretch=tk.NO)
tree.column('three', width=180, stretch=tk.NO)

tree.heading('#0', text='Name', anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading('one', text='Col1', anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading('two', text='Col2', anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading('three', text='Col3', anchor=tk.W)

tree.insert(
    '', 'end', text='The First Item Name',
    values=('Col1_1', 'Col2_1', 'https://test0.test')
)
tree.insert(
    '', 'end', text='The Second Item Name',
    values=('Col1_2', 'Col2_2', 'https://test1.test')
)
tree.insert(
    '', 'end', text='The Third Item Name',
    values=('Col1_3', 'Col2_3', 'https://test2.test')
)

tree.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', tree_click_handler)

root.mainloop()
```